# Integrate between backend (java) & frontend (jsp / js)

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Looking for ideas on the best method to integrate between a backend process running in java / Tomcat (developed in Netbeans) and a third party browser-based app.

The backend process issues commands and data (this can be via XML etc) and, based on those commands / data, I want to ‘automatically’ navigate to specific pages, ‘press buttons’ and ‘fill in fields’ on the third party browser-based app (to which I have no backend / API access).

I am aware of (but have never used) various methods including clipping / integration, portlets, HTML5 comms API’s, Jetspeed etc but is there a simpler / cleaner way of achieving this (ideally some sort of GUI-based toolkit)?

Redoak did have Clipper / Web Integrator but I believe this is no longer being developed / supported.

Thoughts appreciated (I am not the world’s best developer so any tools / frameworks to assist would be appreciated).

Regards
Ralph

Comment: There's a simple answer: `http`. Now you decide how to use it: RESTful services, plain old servlets/jsps called from javascript. So just try to find options for making http requests to your java backend.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no access to the third party front end so I cant make http requests to my backend, integration has to be between backend and third party frontend (via the browser)

Comment: i didn't get what you are looking for , but i can tell you one thing .. forget about GUI-based stuff

Comment: I think I have now found suitable 'browser automation' tools.